# Howto replace hyphen with shy inside paragraph with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

How to search and replace hyphens within paragraphs to &shy?

Tried (with awful result):

```
$s = '<h1>test-1</h1>
<p>multi-plication</p>';
$t = preg_replace('[<p>\-(.*?)</p>]','&shy;',$s);
die($t);
```

if possible, it should look for the hyphen to be surrounded by [a-z] on both sides.

**UPDATE:**
This method is not recommended since it could affect unintentional hypens sucha as tag attributes with class-names etc.

Comment: Don't you love downvotes without comments...

Comment: While not mine, a downvote does not require a comment. If there is not comment assume that it's because `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`.

Comment: The paired `[...]` are used here as regex delimiters, so that part is fine. It is, however, advisable to use DOM to parse the HTML code. Once you get the required node, you may use a mere `str_replace` on its value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, good point. Though that's awful :P.

Comment: Revised after Wiktor's comment: Your regex is currently looking for the literal <p>- etc, which I expect is not what you're looking for. It's also going to replace the entire paragraph, not just the hyphen if it matched.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, wouldn't that affect SEO indexing, or you mean dom-manipulation on server side?

Comment: I am not a SEO expert. All I know is yes, it is possible to do what you want with a regex *if* the HTML you are working with has no nested tags (and yes, you still can even use a regex if the tags are nested - to some extent), but it is just the wrong tool for this task. Getting the right node with DOM/XPath and then performing the replacement on the value is the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

This method is not recommended since it could affect unintentional hypens sucha as tag attributes with class-names etc.